# Error while calling DTS package in to the control flow

Tags: ssis

Have created DTS package for file transformation and i saved as a File system. Now am trying to call that package using "Execute Package Task". I gave all connections, saved and closed the project. When am  re-open the project am trying to execute, while executing it will automatically calls that package and allows to execute. But while executing it will shows error  that the packages "**already opened**"... Task itself open the package then how it will show this error, because of this my entire package will become failed.. Can anyone explain anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are not accessing the package anywhere else? This sounds like concurrency issue to me. Do you launch the package out of process or in the process?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "it will automatically calls that package". Do you mean that you've got one SSIS package calling itself? Two SSIS packages, one calling the other? An SSIS package calling a DTS (SQL Server 2000) package?